# IntelXDK access app path

Tags: android, backbone.js, href, intel-xdk

I am developing an app with Backbone JS and XDK.

I need to launch the App comming from an email link going to a path like index.html/#login/kasdjf98458328/expale@example.com/
We are using a route like myapplication://#login/kasdjf98458328/expale@example.com/ but it doesn' t seem to work. It just goes to the app index.html.

I have read that in native Android you need to specify that the app is BROWSABLE

How can I access the app this way using Intel XDK?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to pass parameters to appmobi or xdk app from android uri. Simply use uri schema://index.html?key=value

You can use intel.xdk.device.queryString to recover the parameters.